# how to create treeview in yii framework

Tags: php, view, yii, tree, treeview

I want to create a tree view which fetching 
data from Database and after that 
order it by parent field 
So table fields are included :

product_category_id

product_category_parent_id

product_category_name

the record that is been mentioned 
by name " product_category_parent_id"
is 0 without any root and when it wish have any 
ID code / number , parent Id should come in this palce
so structure of the table must be sent to the 
View :

```
<ul><li><ul><li></li></ul></li></ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an example how to create CTreeView

```
private function generateTree($models)
{
    $data = array();

    foreach ($models as $category) {
        $data[$category->id] = array(
            'id'   => $category->id,
            'text' => '<a href="/admin/catalog/category/id/'.$category->id.'">'.$category->category_name.'</a>',

        );
        foreach ($category->goods as $item) {
            $data[$category->id]['children'][$item->id] = array(
                'id'   => $item->id,
                'text' =>  '<a href="/admin/catalog/item/id/'.$item->id.'">'.$item->article.'</a>',
                'expanded' => false,
            );
        }

    }
    return $data;
}
```

In view

```
$this->widget('CTreeView', array('data' => $data,'persist'=>'cookie'));
```